# using Rating in ng select angular

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-ngselect

I tried to use p-rating in ng select but when I want to click on Rating the ng select is clicked if I want to just click on Rating but ng select is clicked My problem is that I want to click Rating but after click my dropdown clicked  instead of rating
my html code

```
  <ng-select class="dir" [items]="Menu" bindLabel="title" bindValue="facode" [notFoundText]="NotFoundText"
        (search)="onSearch($event)" placeholder="جستجو در منو..." (change)="selectMenu($event)">
        <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
          <p> {{item.title}} </p>
          <p-rating    stars="1" [cancel]="false"></p-rating>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-select>
```

Please see the photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vRcD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event.stopPropagation(); in your change and search method.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: i try  event.stopPropagation() and work in my project thanks

Comment: Since there are two events which are getting triggered. One is when you click on the star and other is of the select. Since star is on the select, it will trigger the star event first and then the select. event.stopPropagation() prevents the propagation of the event(bubbling up to parent elements or capturing down to child elements).